# Submit form with javascript/jquery after php validation

Tags: php, jquery

Could someone help me with this problem. 
I have to submit a form after I checked if the database doesn't contain the inserted email.

PHP code for email control

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sc_user WHERE email='" . $email . "'";
$select = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_num_rows($select);
$conn_object->connection_signout();

if($row > 0)
  echo "exist";
 else
  echo "notexist";
```

PHP code for inserting new user in database

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_registration']))
  {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sc_user (name, surname, email, password) VALUES ('" . $_POST['user_name'] . "',
     '" . $_POST['user_surname'] . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', '" . md5($_POST['password']) . "')";
if (mysql_query($sql))
    {
    $conn_object->connection_signout();
    }
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Part of the javascript code I have is this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#register_form").submit(function(evReg) {
    evReg.preventDefault();

//other code...

$.post('../PHP/checkMail.php', {'email' : email}, function(data) {
    if(data == 'exist') 
      {
      $('#email_id').val('');
      $('#email_id').attr('placeholder', 'User already registered with this email');
      $('#email_id').addClass('placeholder_red');
      $('#email_id').focus();
      }
    else 
      {
      $(this).submit();
      }
  });
//this.submit();
//other code
```

If I put "this.submit();" outside "$.Post(...);" block the form will submit corectly, but if is inside it's like it doesn't find the form, I think.
Sorry for the english, I hope you will understand my problem.

I've tried using this

```
document.getElementById("register_form").submit();
```

but it doesn't work. I hope I give you all the information you ned.

Comment: Note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection, just so you know.

Comment: Why not combine your PHP so it finishes insert if email doesn't exist, or returns error message.  May be simpler than trying to do two ajax requests.

Comment: Tanks for the answer!

Comment: Becouse I'm usig javascript for handlling the error messagge. I just need to submit the form if the email isn't in the database, [if (data != "exist")]. I just know to do it this way, I am new in programming. I don't now if I make my self clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are inside the scope of the callback function of $.post()  so $(this) doesn't reference properly to your form, you can try changing your code like this:

```
$("#register_form").submit(function(evReg) {
     evReg.preventDefault();
     var $this = $(this);
    //other code
```

and then in your callback function submitting the form using the $this variable

```
if(data == 'exist') 
  {
  $('#email_id').val('');
  $('#email_id').attr('placeholder', 'User already registered with this email');
  $('#email_id').addClass('placeholder_red');
  $('#email_id').focus();
  }
else 
  {
  $this.submit();
  }
```

I haven't tested your code, so i cannot be sure it works but different times this worked for me.

Comment: I've tried as you said but I've got a strange risult.
I made an allert to see what form is stored in the variable "$thisVar" and i got the right answer "register_form", but it goes in an infinite loop, just shows an alert with the name af the form over and over.
I realy don't understand. :(

Comment: alert($thisVar.attr("id")); -> register_form ... $thisVar.submit();

Comment: After allot of testing I realized that the loop is inside [$('#register_form').submit(function......] it is like the submit remains always active so when loads again the page it submites again and again. If I have to make a gues I think is becouse the javascript code is executed before the answer from the server arrives, but I realy don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Thank god and you I solved, after 6 hours of headache i finaly did it. The loop problem I solved with a boolean variable, it is quite brutal but at least works. If someone has a better idea please share it.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, I was thinking about an infinite loop of the submit function, as you said you can use a boolean to stop the loop or use jQuery's serialize() function instead of submit() to serialize your form and send it to your php script using ajax, for more information about the serialize function you can read the official documentation at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/.